# How to preset prop (logged in user) for React component unit test?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm rather new to testing React application, thank you for your time in advance for responding to a newbie question.

So I've been following tutorial on Full Stack Open and came across this challenge about writing tests for React. There is this component Blog which takes some props from App > Blog List > Blog, including one called 'user' which is the returned object from the login function storing username and token etc.

In the Blog's JSX there is a 'remove' button which is shown only to logged in users, controlled by its style determined by a function comparing the username of the original poster of the blog and that of the currently logged in user.

Right now I'm not writing test for username comparison function at all, but it just gets in the way because I can't seem to set a value for 'user' to be passed into the Blog component, and this error was returned during the test:

```
 display: blog.user.username === user.username ? '' : 'none'
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')
```

And here are the codes of the Blog component and the test at current state:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const Blog = ({ blog, addLike, deleteBlog, user }) => {
  const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = useState(false)

  const showWhenDetailsTrue = { display: showDetails ? '' : 'none' }

  const toggleDetails = () => {
    setShowDetails(!showDetails)
  }

  const postedBySelf = async () => {
    const style = await {
      display: blog.user.username === user.username ? '' : 'none',
    }
    return style
  }

  return (
    <div style={blogStyle}>
      <div>
        {blog.title} {blog.author}{' '}
        <button onClick={toggleDetails}>{showDetails ? 'hide' : 'view'}</button>
      </div>
      <div style={showWhenDetailsTrue} className="defaultHidden">
        <div>{blog.url}</div>
        <div>
          likes {blog.likes}
          <button onClick={() => addLike(blog.id)}>like</button>
        </div>
        <div>{blog.author}</div>
        <button onClick={() => deleteBlog(blog)} style={postedBySelf()}>
          remove
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Blog
```

The test file:

```
import React from 'react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Blog from './Blog'

test('renders title and author, but not url or number of likes by default', async () => {
  const blog = {
    title: 'Blog title',
    author: 'Blog author',
    url: 'Blog url',
    user: {
      username: 'mockuser',
    },
  }

  await render(<Blog blog={blog} user={{ username: 'mockuser' }} />)

  screen.getByText('Blog title', { exact: false })
  screen.getAllByText('Blog author', { exact: false })

  const { container } = render(<Blog blog={blog} />)
  const div = container.querySelector('.defaultHidden')
  expect(div).toHaveStyle('display: none')
})
```

When the postedBySelf function and associated content are commented out the test is passed. My question is, how can I mock the 'user' object and pass it into the component during the test? I don't understand why it is undefined even if I explicitly declared its value.

Thanks again for your time and appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Finally spotted my mistake, had to pass in the user in the second rendering of the Blog too.

I wasn't quite sure if I'm missing critical knowledge on this topic but this tutorial explains things very well and helped me spotted the issue in a way. Strongly recommended: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVNjsIto9xM